# Customize Root Path with a dynamic Prefix in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have an application already  done with Symfony2 framework.

The current rooting in the app lok like that :

```
http://testserver.loca.com/app_dev.php/Dashboard/
```

I would like to Add a dynamic prefix like that :

```
http://testserver.loca.com/app_dev.php/Prefix/Dashboard/
```

the dynamic Prefix will be chosen by the user when he click on a link that will send him directly to  the Specific Page, the list will look like:

```
http://testserver.loca.com/app_dev.php/Prefix1/Dashboard/
http://testserver.loca.com/app_dev.php/Prefix2/Dashboard/
http://testserver.loca.com/app_dev.php/Prefix3/Dashboard/
```

I found around that there are a possibility to do it with a Service and an ExtraLoader Class, but i realdon't know how to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the prefix in the routing:

```
/**
 * @Route("{prefix}/Dashboard", name="dynamic_dashboard")
 * @Template()
 */
public function dynamicDashboardAction($prefix)
{
    // Some way of deciding what to do based on prefix
    switch($prefix){
        case 'Prefix1':
            // Do stuff for prefix1 etc
        break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

In the above, the route has a place holder for prefix which is passed to the `dynamicDashboardAction($prefix)` method.  In the view, you can use twig to pass the correct prefix from each link:

```
<a href={{ path("dynamic_dashboard", {"prefix": "Prefix1"}) }}">Dashboard 1</a>
<a href={{ path("dynamic_dashboard", {"prefix": "Prefix2"}) }}">Dashboard 2</a>
```